# Hide link after hitting :target

Tags: css, dom, css-selectors, responsive

I have this https://jsfiddle.net/tbdrLm3q/4/

```
code on js fiddle
```

How do I hide the button (which is a link) after clicking it without affectin the height transition?

Only css please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must add a container like this and change the link to container

`<div id="container">
<a href="#container" class='myButton'>Click</a>
<div id='sharebox'></div></div>`

then

make your css like this

`#container:target #sharebox{
//your style
}`

`#container:target .myButton{
  visibility: hidden;
}`

i hope this usefull :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the final result )))
Pure Css Toggle...
https://jsfiddle.net/tbdrLm3q/6/